# How to convert JSON data into R

Tags: r, json, jsonlite, rjson

```
[
  {
    "type": ["MixedExponential"],
    "mean": [16105.5],
    "sd": [44733.7177],
    "means": [2456, 545, 83553, 2432, 65546],
    "weights": [0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1]
  },
  {
    "type": ["Normal"],
    "mean": [15000],
    "sd": [10000]
  },
  {
    "type": ["LogNormal"],
    "mean": [162754.7914],
    "sd": [1191540.1555],
    "logmu": [10],
    "logsd": [2]
  },
  {
    "type": ["PiecewiseLinear"],
    "mean": [2553.25],
    "sd": [3391.1389],
    "points": [
      {
        "x": 0,
        "Fx": 0
      },
      {
        "x": 0,
        "Fx": 0.05
      },
      {
        "x": 50,
        "Fx": 0.06
      },
      {
        "x": 100,
        "Fx": 0.1
      },
      {
        "x": 200,
        "Fx": 0.3
      },
      {
        "x": 500,
        "Fx": 0.35
      },
      {
        "x": 1000,
        "Fx": 0.5
      },
      {
        "x": 1000,
        "Fx": 0.6
      },
      {
        "x": 2000,
        "Fx": 0.7
      },
      {
        "x": 5000,
        "Fx": 0.79
      },
      {
        "x": 10000,
        "Fx": 0.9
      },
      {
        "x": 10000,
        "Fx": 1
      }
    ],
    "scale": [1],
    "point_masses": [
      {
        "x": 0,
        "Fx": 0.05
      },
      {
        "x": 1000,
        "Fx": 0.1
      },
      {
        "x": 10000,
        "Fx": 0.1
      }
    ],
    "length": [12]
  }
]
```

This is how my JSON data will look like.

So I need it to be converted into a list that contains the 4 objects. 
In the last object, I need "points" and "point_masses" to be data.frames. Every other property should just be an atomic vector.

I obviously have tried to use:

```
jsonlite::fromJSON()
```

But it does not work. It turns the whole thing into a data.frame. And the data appears to be messed up:

```
              type     mean       sd                         means                 weights logmu logsd
1 MixedExponential  16105.5 44733.72 2456, 545, 83553, 2432, 65546 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1  NULL  NULL
2           Normal    15000    10000                          NULL                    NULL  NULL  NULL
3        LogNormal 162754.8  1191540                          NULL                    NULL    10     2
4  PiecewiseLinear  2553.25 3391.139                          NULL                    NULL  NULL  NULL
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  points
1                                                                                                                                                                                                                   NULL
2                                                                                                                                                                                                                   NULL
3                                                                                                                                                                                                                   NULL
4 0.0e+00, 0.0e+00, 5.0e+01, 1.0e+02, 2.0e+02, 5.0e+02, 1.0e+03, 1.0e+03, 2.0e+03, 5.0e+03, 1.0e+04, 1.0e+04, 0.0e+00, 5.0e-02, 6.0e-02, 1.0e-01, 3.0e-01, 3.5e-01, 5.0e-01, 6.0e-01, 7.0e-01, 7.9e-01, 9.0e-01, 1.0e+00
  scale                             point_masses length
1  NULL                                     NULL   NULL
2  NULL                                     NULL   NULL
3  NULL                                     NULL   NULL
4     1 0e+00, 1e+03, 1e+04, 5e-02, 1e-01, 1e-01     12
```

This is the expected output:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$`type`
[1] "MixedExponential"

[[1]]$mean
[1] 16105.5

[[1]]$sd
[1] 44733.72

[[1]]$means
[1]  2456   545 83553  2432 65546

[[1]]$weights
[1] 0.2 0.4 0.1 0.2 0.1


[[2]]
[[2]]$`type`
[1] "Normal"

[[2]]$mean
[1] 15000

[[2]]$sd
[1] 10000


[[3]]
[[3]]$`type`
[1] "LogNormal"

[[3]]$mean
[1] 162754.8

[[3]]$sd
[1] 1191540

[[3]]$logmu
[1] 10

[[3]]$logsd
[1] 2


[[4]]
[[4]]$`type`
[1] "PiecewiseLinear"

[[4]]$mean
[1] 2553.25

[[4]]$sd
[1] 3391.139

[[4]]$points
       x   Fx
1      0 0.00
2      0 0.05
3     50 0.06
4    100 0.10
5    200 0.30
6    500 0.35
7   1000 0.50
8   1000 0.60
9   2000 0.70
10  5000 0.79
11 10000 0.90
12 10000 1.00

[[4]]$scale
[1] 1

[[4]]$point_masses
      x   Fx
1     0 0.05
2  1000 0.10
3 10000 0.10

[[4]]$length
[1] 12
```

Comment: Can you show the output that you expect?

Comment: @cory Thanks for the tip. I just added that

Comment: You could try setting `simplifyDataFrame = F` parameter in `fromJSON()`

Comment: @Sada93 that worked for the most part. But the column names of the "points" and "point_masses" dataframe have been stripped.